# CSS Make a 3 lines inside a div

Tags: css

I have a HTML div generated by a javascript calendar module.

How can I achieve something like this? Using CSS a 2 horizontal and 1 vertical line.

[image]

I cannot put a line below.

Here is my code:

```
.div:before {
    content: "";
    width: 2px;
    height: 84%;
    display: block;
    left: 50%;
    top: 45px;
    position: absolute;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #000, #000, #000);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #000, #000, #000);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #000, #000, #000);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #000, #000, #000);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #000, #000, #000);
}

.div:after {
    content: '';
    width: 38%;
    height: 2px;
    background: black;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 43px;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Border-top, border-bottom, :before for vertical line:

```css
.tick {
  width: 20px;
  height: 100px;
  border-top: 2px solid #555;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #555;
}

.tick:before {
  height: 100%;
  content: '';
  width: 2px;
  background-color: #555;
  left: 9px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="tick"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, but what if the 2 vertical line is not on top and bottom part?  like this https://imgur.com/a/KZLRJ

Answer (score 1):

```css
.line{
  width:1px;
  background: red;
  height: 200px;
  position:relative;
  margin:0 20px;
}
.line:before{
  content:'';
  width:40px;
  border-top:1px solid red;
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  transform:translateX(-50%);
}
.line:after{
  content:'';
  width:40px;
  border-top:1px solid red;
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  transform:translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="line"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, but what if the 2 vertical line is not on top and bottom part? like this imgur.com/a/KZLRJ